# How do I remove CocoaSuite from my Mac?

Tags: snow-leopard

I'm running OS X Snow Leopard & CocoaSuite 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Instructions from official CocoaSuite support*

To deactivate, delete this folder:

```
  /Library/InputManagers/IMM_Loader
```

Other files and folders installed that can be deleted (~ stands for your home directory):

```
  /Applications/InputManagersManager.app
  ~/Library/Application Support/InputManagersManager
  ~/Library/Application Support/CocoaSuite
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the many utilities for removing applications.

For example the free [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/).

Answer (score 1):

if you want do it free you can use:

- [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/)

and if you want to pay a little and gain some extra features use:

- [CleanApp](http://www.syniumsoftware.com/products/cleanapp/index.html)
- [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/)